# Moving to new server = error

Tags: iis, sitecore

I have a pretty standard Sitecore site (no extra assemblies etc., just some layouts and xslt files). The site is working fine on my own server (old w2003 w/iis6). The site now needs to be moved to a new server (w2008 w/iis7). But the site fails to lad, giving this error;

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the following line in the web.config

```
Line 3176:        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Any ideas as to what could be wrong? I dont have access to the server myself, but have just been sent a link to the site, where i can see the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have MVC dependencies you also have to deploy to a new server. [This thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/283818/iis-7-cant-run-asp-net-mvc-application-due-to-missing-system-web-helpers) might be helpful.